# Using exponential distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Jones figures that the total number of thousands of miles that an auto can be driven before it would
need to be junked is an exponential random variable with mean 20. Smith has a used car that he
claims has been driven only 10, 000 miles. If Jones purchases the car, what is the probability that she
would get at least 20,000 additional miles out of it?
\
So I know that this problem uses the exponential distribution. and we are trying to find $ P(x \gt 30 | x \gt 10)$ and because it's a conditional probability we then equate that to $ \frac{1- P(X \le 30) }{ 1- P(X \le 10)}$. I also know that E[X] =$ 1/ \lambda $. \ How do I get from this point to: $\frac{ e ^ {-30/20}  } { e^ {-10/20}} $ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the memoryless property of the exponential distribution $$P(X>30 \mid X>10)=P(X>20)=1-F(20)$$ where $F(x)=1-e^{-λx}$ for $x>0$.

---

In your expression $$\frac{P(X>30)}{P(X>10)}=\frac{1-F(30)}{1-F(10)}=\frac{1-(1-e^{-30/20})}{1-(1-e^{-10/20})}=\frac{e^{-30/20}}{e^{-10/20}}$$

Comment: I've heard of the memoryless property, but how does that apply here in terms of the answer $ {e^{-30/20}}/{e^{−10/20}}  $

Comment: So,
$ F(x) = 1 - e^{x/ - \lambda}$
Then, $ F(x) = 1- e^{-30/20}$ / $ 1 - e^{-10/20}$

I came across that in my notes, $F(x)$ that is, and I wasn't sure how the 1 - part came into play.

Comment: I'm sorry I just can't figure out between my book and my notes why this is so disjoint for me.

Comment: Okay I understand now, thank you @Stef I appreciate your help!